# CSS - background image without url()

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm running my server on Flask, so to insert background like
    background-image: url(/myimage.jpg);
means I have to write a function for this url that returns an image.
Is there a way to paste it without GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out converting your images to base64 data URIs and set them as background images that way. I would not recommend doing so for complex images or large sets of images, as that will increase the size of your style document greatly. Large CSS files will block rendering when placed in the head of HTML documents, which slows down your website by a lot.

Read more on: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm going to hardcode functions for every image =)